# Issue with access and refresh token

Tags: node.js, google-drive-android-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using drive.files.insert method from https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client and it worked properly but I don't know how can I refresh the token and also where can I get the refresh token.
Meanwhile, I am taking the token from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and with that token I am able to upload the files but as the access token valid only for 1 hour so I won't be able to upload the files after 1 hour and I won't know how to do that after 1 hour as I am unable to write get and post method. I saw from some sites, they are using gapi.client for authentication and then they uploading to drive but even it won't work.
I hope I am able to explain my question well.
Suggestions are always welcomed and thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's all correct. Google always give you a token with 1 hour lifetime,  you will not get any longer, but it's not an issue. Read a doc (from the library you pasted here carefully). It says:

> You can start using OAuth2 to authorize and authenticate your requests
>   to Google APIs with the retrieved tokens. If you provide a
>   refresh_token and the access_token has expired, the access_token will
>   be automatically refreshed and the request is replayed.

So if the access_token will be automatically refreshed there is no problem. You can always manually refresh your access token using refresh_token (you always get a pair access_token + refresh_token) but I don't think you need it. It's how Oauth2 works.

Comment: Sir, can you provide me the complete method with some dummy data example for refreshing the token, it would be very helpful for me.

Comment: The library you are suing is full of samples. Analyzing your question I'm not sure if you fully understand how the oAuth2 protocol works. I don't recommend you to refresh the token yourself. If the user gives you one the permission to use the app you just authorize the request each time when you need it. I suggest you to read https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer and pay attention to 'Calling Google APIs' section. Good luck!